# Visual Studio 2019 Community WinForm VB .NET ¿Como puedo mostrar los datos de una tabla en un componente RDLC/ReportViewer con base de datos SQLIte?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, reportviewer, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un proyecto del tipo **Windows Form** con **Visual Studio 2019 Community**.

Para almacenar los datos deseo usar una base de datos **SQlite** y utilizo el Nuget **System.Data.SQLite**, actualmente estoy usando este código para el CRUD en los formularios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero surge un problema, y es que el IDE no reconoce a SQLite como componente **ADO .NET** a la hora de establecer la conexión con la base de datos como origen de datos para componentes como DataSet que necesito el el **diseñador de informes RDLC de Microsoft**, y por extensión no logro mostarlos en el **ReportViewer de Microsoft**.

He buscado por muchos lugares, pero ninguno deja claro como hacerlo, algunos dependen de componentes de paga como DevArt para ello, y otros simplemente parecen ser de versiones de Visual Studio 2012 o 2013, que actualmente resultan problematicas de adquirir, y además parecen edits falsos/engañosos o demasiado incompletos para servirme de ayuda.

Gracias por dedicar su tiempo para leer mi problema, agradecería mucho si compartes sus opiniones o aportes para solucionar este problema.

Comment: Y porque no lo agregas como objeto de datos https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBhTw.png

Comment: Estaré probando esta opción... me comunicaré si ofrece resultados.

Comment: Respuesta: Nada, Visual Studio no reconoce mi base de datos SQLite como objeto para origen de datos

Comment: Creo que no entendiste la idea. Tu creas clases que corresponden a la tabla (o resultado de la consulta), agregas esa clase como objeto de dato y con tienes los campos del dataset. Luego desde VB haces la consulta y envías esos datos al reporte mediante código